# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have a `User` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy

  # here, I want to get :collected_posts (all posts that all user collections have)
  # has_many :collected_posts, through: :collections, source: :post (this throws error)
end
```

This is my `Post` model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_collections, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This is my `Collection` model

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_collections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :post_collections
end
```

This is my `PostCollection` model

```
class PostCollection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

I want to do `current_user.collected_posts` to get all the posts he saved in all his collections.

But, I get this error

```
# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) :post in model Collection. Try 'has_many :collected_posts, :through => :collections, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user, post_collections, or posts?)
```

because there is no `post_id` in a collection object.

How can I get all the posts all user collections have?
Thanks!

Comment: So user has many collections, collections have many post collections, and post collections have many posts, but you are trying to connect user to posts.  You might want to think about restructuring this.  Can you include the schema for these objects?

Comment: @NickEllis, Hi. `User` has_many `posts` and `post` has a `user_id` column. I can do `user.posts` to get posts of a user. But, I also want `user.collected_posts` to get all the posts this user has saved in his collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `User` class

```
has_many :collected_posts, through: :collections, source: :posts
```

Comment: Does this work?  I think this will go from user to collections to posts, but the question is asking about user to collections to post_collections to posts.  I think this is a grandparent grandchild relation rather than the great grandparent relation being described.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so in the user model

```
 def collected_posts
   self.collections.map(&:posts).flatten
 end
```

user has collections the collections have posts (through post collections) the map function will call that function on each collection object and return the posts.

Comment: Thank you Nick. Is there any way to do it via the `has_many` way though. Just curious.

Comment: Not that I know of.  As I understand the has_many you can do it as a direct parent child relation, or through a join table making it more of a grandparent grandchild relation.  Yours is a great grandparent to great grandchild relation which is an order of magnitude more complex so I would not expect ActiveRecord to have an out of the box functionality to deal with it.